# How to place my Actionbar item to the left side, before title?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, positioning, android-actionbar-compat

How to move my actionbar item to the left side of the ACTIONBAR, before the title? I have two items, edit and settings, I need my items placed both on the right and left side, but it places by default on the right, how can i change it?

Comment: create custom view and set that as actionbarView

Comment: Can't i do it without setCustomView, like navigation drawer button?

Answer (score 3):

in the Activity

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_action_bar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

my_action_bar.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/turquoise">

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/btn_slide"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_slide"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is hide the actionbar title by following way:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Then place them in item menu as you wish in your order.

Comment: And then you would create a horrible application!